# What are the new SQL functions being introduced in the SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

What are the new features being introduced in the SQL SERVER 2014?

Comment: why negative? is there any questions in sql server 2014 group :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the benefits of SQL Server 2014 will vary based on your specific use cases, but the features that we're finding compelling and are causing us to plan to upgrade are as follows:

- *New cardinality estimator*  - improves the execution plans that we're seeing for some of our more complex queries, and definitely assists with the ascending key problem
- *AlwaysOn enhancements* - you can now have 8 readable secondary nodes rather than 4, and readable secondary replicas now allow read workloads even in the case of loss of quorum
- *Delayed durability*
- *In-Memory OLTP*

Some more details on changes in 2014 can be found at http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/sql-server-2014-important-new-features and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435(v=sql.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: We are on SQL Server 2012.  We are not planning to use any of the new features in 2014. Will there still be some benefits, such as faster execution of queries or something?

Comment: The new cardinality estimator is the feature that is most likely to bring you faster execution of some queries (because it can lead to improved execution plans in certain cases).  That has certainly been our experience.  Of course for some queries it leads to worse execution plans (and for many no change in the execution plan).  In our environment it has, overall, led to improvements though.